# Autocompleteextender - HTTP 403.9 - Access Forbidden: Too many users are connected Internet Information Services

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have two textbox in a page each uses ASP.Net Ajax Autocompleteextender control.

asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="PlainText" 
    MaxLength="50"

Ajax:autocompleteextender id="aceLastName" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtLastName"
    servicepath="~/AjaxService/Predictive.svc" servicemethod="GetLastName" minimumprefixlength="1"
    completioninterval="100" completionsetcount="8" EnableCaching="False"

asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="PlainText" 
    MaxLength="50" 
Ajax:autocompleteextender id="aceFirstName" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtFirstName"
    servicepath="~/AjaxService/Predictive.svc" servicemethod="GetFirstName" minimumprefixlength="1"
    completioninterval="100" completionsetcount="8" EnableCaching="False"

However after typing certain characters all of a sudden Autocompleteextender stops working. Upon refresing the page i get HTTP 403.9 - Access Forbidden: Too many users are connected Internet Information Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I was not closing connection to webservice, so with each key press it was opening a new connection.